# Format of a Magento attribute value of type Date

Tags: date, magento

If I have an attribute called `myDateAttribute` of type Date in Magento and want to retrieve its value for a certain product, I will simply make the following call:

```
$date = $product->getMyDateAttribute();
```

What is the format of the date now stored in the `$date` variable? Is it MM/DD/YYYY, or does it depend on some locale settings (if so, how can I get these locale settings?)?

In any case, I would like to have it as DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss in the end. Is there some way to specify a format conversion or should I just do the re-formatting manually?

Thanks for your help in case you have any useful suggestions :)

Comment: Have you tried dumping that variable to check on the format?

Comment: Yes, it is of the form MM/DD/YY. But the problem is I am writing a module that may be used with several Magento installations. Can I be sure that this will always be the format of a Date attribute?

Comment: Nothing in life is assured :) You can use strtotime to parse the date if it's in any sane format, and then put it back out in whatever format you want. Then you won't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can change between 12/31/2012 and 31 December 2012 like this:

```
$date = $product->getMyDateAttribute();
$format = 'long'; // short, long, medium, full
return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($date, $format, $showTime=false);
```

You can also change it from the admin section (as previously answered):

> System -> Configuration -> CATALOG -> Catalog -> Date & Time Custom Options -> Date Fields Order

Finally, you can hard-code in a date format like this:

```
$date = $product->getMyDateAttribute();
$format = 'm/d/Y'; // Or whatever the current format is
$formatted_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date)
    ->format('d-m-Y  H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

There is date time settings in Magento.

Go to :-

> System -> Configuration -> CATALOG -> Catalog -> Date & Time Custom
>   Options -> Date Fields Order

You can set the date field order from there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried changing this setting, but the value stored in my Date attribute when I echo it out is still of the form MM/DD/YY. Can I assume it will always be like this, in any Magento installation?